# Specs2: How to turn a Seq[Matcher[A]] into a single Matcher[A]?

Tags: scala, specs, specs2

Given a sequence `Seq[Matcher[A]]` I want to obtain a single `Matcher[A]` that succeeds when all matchers inside the sequence succeed.

#### Edit

The answer provided by myself seems a bit clumsy and in addition it would be nice if all failing matchers of the sequence produced a result

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've found a way:

```
(matchers: Seq[Matcher[A]]).reduce(_ and _)
```

Somehow I thought there has to be a different way, like writing `_.sequence`.

Comment: damn! 3 minutes, that was fast

Comment: I think my brain is close to exploding. I just can't see the red line in the use of this library.

Comment: Then don't use it, scala plays nice with `JUnit` too

Comment: The thing is as long as you use the provided matchers it works great. But somehow I'm not able to build new matchers by reusing the existing ones. Either I'm not clever enough or it doens't work well. I want to find out.

Comment: sorry can't help you there, I've never built one either

Comment: If you implement a `Monoid[Matcher[_]]`, then `matchers.collapse` ought to work. Interestingly, on `Boolean`, Scalaz's Monoid is `|`, not `&`. I think I saw a way to switch that, but I can't recall.

Comment: @Daniel Is Matcher a Monoid? How does flatMap look?

Comment: @ziggystar Monoid, not Monad. Monoid requires an associative dot: a -> a -> a, with identity. Like (Int, +, 0) and (Int, *, 1).

Comment: Actually there would be 2 ways to turn Matcher into a Monoid, either the AndMonoid where all the matchers have to succeed or OrMonoid, where just one of them has to succeed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with creating a new matcher from the matcher sequence is that it becomes harder to find which matcher failed.

The better option in my opinion is to match against each matcher separately like so:

```
val matchers: Seq[Matcher[Boolean]] = Seq(
  ((_: Boolean).equals(false), "was true 1"),
  ((_: Boolean).equals(true), "was false 2"),
  ((_: Boolean).equals(true), "was false 3")
)

"work with matcher sequence" in {
  matchers.foreach(beMatching => false must beMatching)
}
```

You can see from the output that the matchers are invoked separately and the first failure causes a test failure with the message *of that matcher*.

Depending on the case you have it might even be better to generate Expectations for each matcher, so it will execute them all and show you a proper overview, not just the first failure. I didn't go that far (yet).